# strange c++ arithmetic

Tags: c++

I'm a bit puzzled by the value of `h` in this experiment. In cpp,

```
int h,J=3,n=200,p=3,h_m=(n+p+1)/2;
float rt=(float)h_m/n;

for(int j=0,j<J,j++){
   h=floor((j+1)/J*rt*(n-p-1)+p+1);
   std::cout<<h<<" "<<j<<" "<<rt<<" "<<n-p-1<<" "<<h_i<<" "<<J<<std::endl;
}
```

gives:

```
4 0 0.51 196 7  3
4 1 0.51 196 7  3
103 2 0.51 196 7  3
```

I'm trying to get (this is in R):

```
n<-200
p<-3
h_m<-as.integer((n+p+1)/2)
J<-3
j<-0:(J-1)
rt<-h_m/n
floor((j+1)/J*rt*(n-p-1)+p+1)
[1]  37  70 103
```

what is wrong in the cpp construct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
(j+1)/J
```

is integer division, and therefore gets truncated. Expicitly cast one of the operands to float:

```
(j+1)/(float)J
```

Comment: R uses double-precision floats internally, too. So if you want to do more closely match R's precision you should use double wherever you want floating point.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `static_cast<float>(J)` since this is a c++ question? C style casts are kind of discouraged afterall

Comment: @Grizzly i dont see the problem for numeric conversions.